# Java import mysql database /bin/bash error

Tags: java, mysql, database, bash, bin

I want to create database import using .sql file with java then I found a code something like this

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","mysql -p -h localhost test < "+fileName.toString()});
```

I'm using netbean to run my desktop app. then I got this error message

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

my question is where can i find /bin/bash path? or what should i do...
should I configure something like env variable path?

I'm running this on windows

solution is replacing /bin/bash with cmd.exe and -c to /c, but when I execute the program I got this message appear on my console

*'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

though I already setup mysql directory in PATH environment variable of Windows

Comment: Is this on Linux? Can you run `/bin/bash` in a terminal/console, outside of Java?

Comment: You are trying to run `/bin/bash` on Windows?

Comment: I'm on windows 
@Philipp: I'm on  windows when I type on cmd '/bin/bash/' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @Angga Saputra Answer is simple.. "The way you run the process in windows Command Prompt, use the same in exec() method "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/bin/bash` doesn't exist on Windows.  Try replacing `/bin/bash` with `cmd.exe`, and replacing the switch `-c` with `/c`.

**EDIT**: if your Java program appears to complete successfully but no data has been written, it is quite possible that your Java program didn't wait for the `mysql` process to complete.  Try adding `pr.waitFor();`.

Alternatively, `mysql` could be reporting an error message or writing something to its standard output or standard error streams.  If this is the case, you'll need to either:

1. read the offending stream(s), or
2. if you're sure you can ignore it, redirect the offending stream(s) to `NUL`.

You can redirect standard output to `NUL` by adding `>NUL` to the command line, and redirect standard error to `NUL` by adding `2>NUL`.

I woudn't recommend discarding the output/error messages.  If there's an error, how will you know about it?  However, it's difficult to properly handle the standard output and standard error streams of processes generated using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`.  Instead, I would use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  A ProcessBuilder allows you to redirect the `mysql` process's standard error into the standard output, which makes reading the output from both streams a bit easier (you don't need two separate threads).

```java
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "mysql -p -h localhost test < "+fileName.toString());
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process pr = builder.start();

// Get mysql process's standard output/error.
InputStream is = pr.getInputStream();

// Now read from it and write it to standard output.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: wow great thanks @Luke it works now, but my database is not successfully imported ..when I try "mysql -p -h localhost test < mydb.sql" on command prompt that mysql command was success

Comment: @AnggaSaputra: what do you mean by 'not successfully imported'?  Do you get an error message?  Does your Java program hang?  Does your program appear to complete successfully but no data is in your database?

Comment: my bad.. I mean yes it does complete but no data in my database..it's still empty

Comment: I've tried replace pr.exec command with "dir" then it's print my current dir program...then I replace command with "mysql" only and does not show anything..

Comment: thanks luke, I've been printing the error message with pr.getErrorStream() and now the problem is mysql command was not detected as a command by my cmd.exe, do you know why this is happening? though I already setup on my environment variable PATH

Comment: @AnggaSaputra: is it on the PATH that your Java program gets?  What does `System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));` print?

Comment: PATH on windows environment variable, I add mysql path directory to PATH ....System.getenv("PATH") result only show this C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver...no mysql path directory

Comment: I don't know how you're launching your Java program, nor do I know everything about your computer's environment.  It seems it's now a configuration issue on your computer.  Until you can get the path to `mysql` into the output of `System.getenv("PATH")`, `mysql` will not work.  I'm going to have to leave it to you to sort this one out.

Comment: thanks 4 your great help...I restart my machine then mysql path added to PATH...thanks..its all because of you...